# How to loop multiway anova

Tags: r, anova

It's my first couple of weeks using R and I've been breaking my head over a problem. I hope you guys can help me out!

I'm doing a multiway ANOVA (aov(Eicosane~SEX+STATUS,data=data_wide). Now I have about 26 different dependent variables, which are chemical compounds(in this example Eicosane) found on Drosophila suzukii fruit flies and I want to see if the chemical compound found can be addressed to sex or status. Is there a way to use some kind of loop so I don't need to change the dependent variable manually each time and can get the output in 1 file?

```
Someone recommended; {For (i in 1:26)}
(aov(i ~SEX+STATUS,data=data_wide)}
Result}
```

But it gives Error: unexpected 'in'. Does R automatically number my colums in my dataset as 1,2,3 etc... ?

I hope it's a bit clear and my apologies for this newbie question but I just can't seem to figure it out myself.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi there, welcome to the community and R! May I suggest that you edit your question to include a reproducible example ("reprex")? That'll make it much easier to help you find an answer. Here are some sources on how to make a reprex, https://github.com/jennybc/reprex#reproducible-examples (another source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
data(prostate, package= "faraway")
for (i in 1:ncol(prostate)) {
  print(summary(aov(prostate[,i] ~., data= prostate)))
}
```

In this case I use all columns vs the 1 remaining in the call to `aov`. If you wish to exclude `SEX` and `STATUS` from your set of dependent variables, you'll have to modify the call in the for loop, eg:

```
cols <- (1:ncol(data_wide))[-c(which(names(data_wide) %in% c("SEX", "STATUS")))]
for (i in cols) {...}
```

Comment: Exactly what I need! Thanks a lot!